# How can i get javascript to conserve the input fields when doing an action?

Tags: javascript, html

i made a small script that takes values from two inputs and change them when clicking on submit,

```js
function remplacer() {
            var v1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
            var v2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;
            document.getElementById("val1").value = v2;
            document.getElementById("val2").value = v1;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <label for="">entrez la valuer 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">                
    <br>                
    <label for="">entrez la valuer 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="button_remp" value="Remplace" onclick="remplacer()">
</form>
```

the only problem is that the page reloads and the resualt flashes really fast, does anyone have any insight on this and thanks.
edit, for some reason the code snippet is working fine, but when i open the page in chrome/firefox it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, Generally input type submit post data to form action. if you want to use button for javascript event then you have to say type="button".

```js
function remplacer() {
            var v1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
            var v2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;
            document.getElementById("val1").value = v2;
            document.getElementById("val2").value = v1;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <label for="">entrez la valuer 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">                
    <br>                
    <label for="">entrez la valuer 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="button_remp" value="Remplace" onclick="remplacer()">
</form>
```

Comment: for some reason it's working here but when i try to run it on my browser it's not the case.

Comment: Try adding action="#". in your code also check if console does have other error.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitted and that reloads the page

You COULD change the submit button to type="button" but I suggest you

1. use the submit event
2. preventDefault

```js
document.getElementById('remplacerForm').addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the submit
  var v1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
  var v2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;
  document.getElementById("val1").value = v2;
  document.getElementById("val2").value = v1;
})
```

```html
<form id="remplacerForm">
  <label for="">entrez la valuer 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">
  <br>
  <label for="">entrez la valuer 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="button_remp" value="Remplace">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with this. I tried making it on my own and this worked for me! Hope it works for you too:

```html
documdocument.getElementById('remplacerForm').addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the submit
  var v1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
  var v2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;
  document.getElementById("val1").value = v2;
  document.getElementById("val2").value = v1;
})
<form id="remplacerForm">
  <label for="">entrez la valuer 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">
  <br>
  <label for="">entrez la valuer 2:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="buttonremp" value="Remplace">
</form>
```